# Converse of a well known result.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We all know the following result.

**Let $\sum a_n$ is a series of alternative positive and negative terms. Consider $p_n = \frac{a_n + |a_n|}{2}$ and $q_n = \frac{a_n - |a_n|}{2}$. So $\sum p_n$ and $\sum q_n$ are series of positive and negative terms of $\sum a_n$. Now if $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely, then both the series of positive and negative terms $\sum p_n$ and $\sum q_n$ are convergent. Similarly if $\sum a_n$ converges conditionally, then both $\sum p_n$ and $\sum q_n$ diverges.**

I want to know if its converse is true i.e. I am interested with the result.

1. If $\sum p_n$ and $\sum q_n$ converges then $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent.
2. If $\sum p_n$ and $\sum q_n$ diverges then $\sum a_n$ is conditionally convergent.

How to prove? I am not seeing its converse in my text book. If not please give some counterexamples.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: On what condition does $a_n$ diverge?

Comment: (2) for this one, try $p_n = 1/n$ and $q_n = -1/n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is true, because if two series converge absolutely, their termwise sum also converges absolutely.

(2) is false. Counterexample: $a_n = (-1)^n$.